# Flutter: DateTime format

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

Sorry if the code isn't well formatted.

I had a look to the other related subjects but i can't get it right (apparently the best way is .toDate() ). I am a newb so, I am not sure where to do it right. The code works fine but the date in the chat is not user friendly so I wanted to format DateTime.now() to be 'yMd' way (this piece of code `'time': DateFormat('yMd').format(DateTime.now()),`) .  If I use the DateTime.now() works fine. And `"$sender ${time.toDate()}",`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCz5v.png)

[So this is the format that I get following the tuto, but I wanted to make it more simple...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW1jN.png)

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'chat_screen';

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                //  getMessages();
                // messagesStream();
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                        'time': DateFormat('yMd').format(DateTime.now()),
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      //de donde vienen los mensajes (data)
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      //
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data()['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];
          final messageTime = message.data()['time'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageWidget = MessageBubble(
            text: messageText,
            sender: messageSender,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
            time: messageTime,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageWidget);
          messageBubbles.sort((a, b) => b.time.compareTo(a.time));
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10,
              vertical: 20,
            ),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble({this.sender, this.text, this.isMe, this.time});
  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;
  final Timestamp time; //added

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "$sender ${time.toDate()}",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, color: Colors.black54),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  )
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
            elevation: 9.0,
            color: isMe
                ? Colors.lightBlueAccent
                : Colors.redAccent, //Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 20.0,
                vertical: 10.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                '$text',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black54,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you see and what exactly do you want to get? Share a screenshot or examples

Comment: Timestamp is not a type ? You use a package for Timestamp ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I forgot to write what the message error says so I just edited the post, the image  is in the link. So `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'`, according to VSCode, is on the line where return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>. I suppose I have to modify something in order to accept the String value that comes from the dateformat...I don't know

Comment: Then your error has absolutely nothing to do with formatting a date string and everything to do with you passing a string to something that is expecting a `Timestamp`.

Comment: I am checking other' people work on github but they're almost the same (since this is a old tuto). I'll be back if I can figure it out. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Surferus I suggest looking into this line: `_firestore.collection('messages').add`

Comment: Yes that's the line I am trying to work with, for the moment. Some people used `'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` instead of `DateTime.now()`. Nobody has made big changes since this was a simple tuto a also it's already old. it's a waste of time for a simple detail so I am just gonna keep going and maybe I'll have an idea with probably more knowledge. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp is an integer.

```dart
"$sender ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore gives you timestamps with its [`Timestamp`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp-class.html) class, which represents an epoch timestamp (i.e. milliseconds/microseconds since the epoch, a.k.a. January 1st, 1970 at 12:00 AM UTC). You will have to convert this to a date before you can format it.

As far as the actual formatting, the most straightforward way to do this is with the [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package. There is a [`DateFormat`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class with presets for all the common formatting options, including "yMd":

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

...

final now = Timestamp.now();
final formatted = DateFormat.yMd().format(now.toDate());
```

Comment: I tried to apply what you suggested but the error pops up every time.